# How do we increase the c-rate (discharge rate) of any electrical system?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, discharge

I have limited understanding of electricity and electronics in general. I know Ohm's law; V=IR, which to me means current depends on voltage and resistance.

So let's say if I want to draw more current to go at higher speeds on my electric vehicle, I either have to increase the voltage or decrease the resistance. But motors are specified with their voltage rating, so voltage must remain constant. So the only variable is resistance. So to go at faster speeds I'll have to reduce the load? How is this achieved? I am confused.

Comment: What motor are you using?

Comment: A motor has many more degrees of freedom to its design than just voltage and resistance. Obviously size is one, but even motors of the same size can have a different no-load RPM when running off the same voltage.

Comment: let's say I am have a battery with 51 volts output and 70Ah capacity driving a 50 V motor. I want to know how we can increase the C rate in this system. Like suppose I want to draw 160Amps, then how I'll do it?

Comment: You use a motor that is wound differently or has a different number of poles so that it has a higher RPM per volt. If your goal is to change the way it performs without changing any components then you're trying to change something without changing anything.

Comment: @DKNguyen, but since the voltage is remaining same, and current is increasing, that means resistance should decrease right??

Comment: @ShaileshJoshi A motor is not just a resistance. Furthermore, a motor does not need resistance to operate. So focusing on the motor resistance isn't helping you. Winding a motor to turn faster does result in a reduced resistance but that is irrelevant. You can make a motor with super conducting wire if you want and it would still run as a motor. Focusing on resistance would be like focusing on the friction in the cylinders of an engine to try and figure out its power output. Just reducing the resistance or friction increases efficiency more efficient but doesn't fundamentally increase power.

Comment: What a motor does need to run is the generator effect. That is, for every RPM rotated it produces a certain amount of back EMF voltage. That is what you should focus on. Not resistance. The issue you run into though is that the size of a motor affects how much power it can handle, so just winding it to spin faster per volt might increase power output but does not increase power capability. If you keep your motor the same size and it was already designed near the power limit, you won't be able to safely squeeze more power out of it. The motor just burns out from too much power density.

Comment: if you are concerned about motor power and speed, then ohms law is the wrong tool to use. It's like trying to steer your car by turning the rear view mirror. Research motors, power, speed, current. voltage. An ideal motor has zero resistance. Speed is proportional to voltage, torque proportional to current, and they are essentially independent.

Comment: Consider also your motor's demand for current and the battery's ability to supply it. While the battery in a car is 12v and you can buy miniature 12v lighter/remote-control batteries, you certainly can't start an automobile using 1 of those miniature batteries. If on the other hand, you had a *lot* (i.e 10s of kilograms) of those small cells wired in parallel, you could start the car. If the motor is trying to draw more current than the battery can supply before its voltage (and as a result, its supplied current) drops, you could put several identical batteries in parallel.